# Android - sending only required json

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, deserialization

I can't figure this one out at all. Assuming I have products serialized as JSON being retrieved from a server, and once product info has been received by the Android app it's stored locally on the file system, how would I accomplish the following?

Let's say I have a list of products sent by the server (for instance highest rated products, or search results, etc).  I want to be able to have the server only send the full json data for objects that are not currently stored on the device, otherwise just the id of the product. I could send a list of products that are stored on the device, but it would obviously defeat the purpose. I could also just send back a list of product IDs from the server and the device can request the ones it needs from there. This takes one request and turns it into multiple requests, so not ideal either. These are the only two options I can think of at this point for this.

Furthermore, it may be that of the 30 fields or so in the product json, 1 or 2 may have changed (price or rating).  How can I find out if it has changed without sending the entire products or certain fields? Currently I am sending a product id with the md5 of the json and if it matches what's on the device, then don't send, but if the two hashes don't match, then don't send. Again, I think this might be best case scenario but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to track the state of your app on server. This means that your app should **sign in** (or do anything that would allow server to hand it a unique token used to know that this is particular client "instance"). Then your app have to tell the server what IDs it already have (or fetch all from server). Server should always note what IDs is sent to client (or record these told by app)). Since each call to server should be accompanied with the token, server can easily know what is your state at that point (unless you i.e. logout, timeout or invalidate token in any other way).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is you could separate the hashes of fields that usually change together, e.g. you could have a hash for (price, rating) and another hash for the fields describing the object itself. The device can then request only the set of fields it needs to update.

Another thing you could try is to use 32-bit unix timestamps instead of hashes. Assuming you're consistent and that you don't update your objects more than once a second, you'll save some bandwidth, as compared to the 128-bit MD5 sum.